# HTML5/JavaScript: Store Dynamic Variable Name and Value in localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, variables, dynamic, local-storage

I would like to store the value `yes` into localStorage with a key of `movie1` using javascript. However, I want the `1` part of the key to be dynamic based on whatever `movieID` is set to.

This is what I currently have, but it isn't working:

```
movieID = 1;

localStorage.movie + movieID = 'yes';
```

Any thoughts or insight on how I can accomplish this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

```
localStorage['movie'+movieID] = 'yes';
```

Comment: ...searched for hours through the web - this works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 13):

You can use the setItem function to store values in local storage:

```
localStorage.setItem('movie' + movieID, 'yes');
```

Then later when you want to check the value, you can use

```
localStorage.getItem('movie' + movieID);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think

```
localStorage.setItem('movie' + movieID, 'yes');
```

is actually a helper in a library usage and is not official.

Comment: What do you mean by "actually a helper in a library usage"? The code you have posted is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZwhBY/

Check out square brackets for properties.

http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html

Comment: Thank you for the jsfiddle. This works and is basically the same answer as stewe, but a little more in depth...I just prefer being able to see the answer right away on stackoverflow without having to switch over to jsfiddle.